# Revert back to full screen after using set columns=X

Tags: default-settings

If I `set columns=X`, how can I get back to "normal"? Saving the original value might be one way to go, but if I resize the terminal between saving and reverting I'll be ending up with the wrong columns again.

Comment: Resizing the window seems to reset the `&columns` value, at least for me. I think saving it is your only option. You can hook in to the `VimResized` autocmd to get the new `&columns` default.

Comment: Try `:!tput cols`

Comment: That'll return whatever you set `&columns` to @D.BenKnoble (on my system, anyway)

Comment: The `:!tput cols` works for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Although _actually_ my problem is starting to be the other way around. So vim actually resets the columns whenever the terminal is resized, which is obviously great in general, but that means passing `vim -c "set columns=X"` actually get overrided by the time vim actually fires up.

Comment: The use case I'm trying to solve, is reading and writing unwrapped email on a wide screen without having to read kilometer long lines and columns seems like a nice choice (the alternative I'm seeing is opening an empty buffer to the right).